Is it possible to define a function of several matrix variables whose inputs are variables in Sage?
I have a very little knowledge about Sage and this may be a dumb question, but I could not find anything about this.
Is there any way to define a sage function of several variables whose arguments are matrices (e.g. automorphy factor of Siegel modular group)? In other words, can we define a function of matrix variables whose entries are variables.
I have no experience whatsoever in sage and I am sorry if this sounds silly.

You can define variables using vars = var('x11 x12 x21 x22') (using loops to build the string with variable names), then operate in MatrixSpace(SR,m,n) = $m\times n$ matrix ring over the 'symbolic ring' (it includes all variables you defined). What kind of function do you want?

Sorry for the late reply. I want a function which maps $M_n(Z)\times \mathbb C^n$ to $\mathbb C^n$ which explicitly depends on the entries of the matrices. i.e., if given any pair of symbolic matrices, it returns the image as a symbolic vector.

(can't post multiline code in comments)
What should it compute? Here's a mathematically nonsensical example (I hope I captured the general idea of your question):
n = 4 # even dimension
MS = MatrixSpace(SR,n,n) # define the matrix space

# Define the 2D list (a list of lists) that's about to become
# a matrix with named variables (matrices in SageMath are immutable):
ml = [ [0]*n for i in range(n)] 
# Generate the named variables and add them to the list in the usual order:
for i in range(n): # 0...n-1
    for j in range(n):
        # This injects the variable name into the SR:
        ml[i][j] = var('m'+str(i)+str(j))
M = MS(ml) # make the 2D list a matrix
# Generate the vector (0,1,2,...,n-1):
v = VectorSpace(SR,n)(list(range(n)))

# The function.
def f(m, t):
    # Split the vector in half:
    v0 = t[:n//2]; v1 = t[n//2:]
    # Split the matrix into 4 blocks:
    m.subdivide([n//2], [n//2])
    # Take the lower two ones:
    C = m.subdivision(1,0); D = m.subdivision(1,1)
    # Multiply the half-vectors by inverses of half-matrices,
    # reconstruct the long vector and operate upon it too:
    return m*vector(list(C^-1*v0) + list(D^-1*v1))

f(M,v) # evaluate the example

Please ask any questions on notation, or post the formula you want to adjust the above computation to.
